# Item/Ability system using scriptableobjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm having some trouble creating scriptable objects for items to pick up and use in my project. I've created the initial set-up to make the items with variables that I can plug-and-play with.

What I'm trying to do is:

1 - plug in a monobehavior script for each new item's behavior when used.

2 - Allow the player to pick up the item on collision and use the item on key command. The player should only carry one item at a time.

Here is what I have so far.

the scriptable object (itemObject.cs)

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Item")]
public abstract class Item : ScriptableObject {
                public new string name;
                public string description;
                public int damageAmount;
                public int affectDelay;
                public int affectDuration;
                public int affectRange;
                public float dropChance;
                public float itemLife;
}
```

I have a script that will trigger if the player collides with the object (itemDisplay.cs)
Currently, this doesn't do anything but destroys the item.

```
public class itemDisplay : MonoBehaviour {

public Item item;

public static bool isActive = false;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {

        var playerPickUp = other.gameObject;

        var playerScript = playerPickUp.GetComponent<Player>();
        var playerItem = playerScript.playerItem;

        playerScript.pickUpItem();

        bool isActive = true;

        Object.Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}


void Start () {

}


void Update(){
}
```

}

Currently, I have a pickup function and a use item function that's being handled by my player script(Player.cs). Currently, this just toggles a boolean saying that it did something when the item is collided with. My big question is how/where should I create and reference the item ability and how do I pass it to the player script here?

```
public void pickUpItem()
{
    playerItem = true;
    //itemInHand = itemInHand;
    Debug.Log("You Picked Up An Item!");

   // Debug.Log(playerItem);
    if(playerItem == true){
        Debug.Log("This is an item in your hands!");
    }

}

public void useItem()
{
    //use item and set
    //playerItem to false
    playerItem = false;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "how do I create an instance of an `Item` in my project", you do that by right clicking in your Project view, then selecting `Create -> Item`.  Then drag the `Item` asset that you created from your Project view into the `ItemDisplay` scene object's `item` field in the Inspector.

Regarding how to pick up the item, you would pass the item to your `Player` script from your `ItemDisplay` script.  You've got most of that already wired up.

```
public class ItemDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
      if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
      {
         var playerPickUp = other.gameObject;

         var playerScript = playerPickUp.GetComponent<Player>();
         var playerItem = playerScript.playerItem;

         // This is where you would pass the item to the Player script
         playerScript.pickUpItem(this.item);

         bool isActive = true;

         Object.Destroy(gameObject);
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your `Player` script...

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void PickUpItem(Item item)
   {
      this.playerItem = true;
      this.itemInHand = item;
      Debug.Log(string.Format("You picked up a {0}.", item.name));
   }

   public void UseItem()
   {
      if (this.itemInHand != null)
      {
         Debug.Log(string.Format("You used a {0}.", this.itemInHand.name));
      }
   }
}
```

You should also make your `Item` class non-abstract, or leave it abstract and create the appropriate non-abstract derived classes (`Weapon`, `Potion`, etc.).  I put an example of that below.

You can't attach a `MonoBehaviour` to a `ScriptableObject` if that's what you're trying to do.  A `ScriptableObject` is basically just a data/method container that isn't tied to a scene.  A `MonoBehaviour` has to live on an object within a scene.  What you could do however, is add a "use" method to your `Item` class, and call that from a `MonoBehaviour` within the scene when the player uses an item.

```
public abstract class Item : ScriptableObject
{
   // Properties that are common for all types of items
   public int weight;
   public Sprite sprite;

   public virtual void UseItem(Player player)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}


[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Items/Create Potion")]
public class Potion : Item
{
   public int healingPower;
   public int manaPower;

   public override void UseItem(Player player)
   {
      Debug.Log(string.Format("You drank a {0}.", this.name));

      player.health += this.healingPower;          
      player.mana += this.manaPower;
   }
}

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Items/Create Summon Orb")]
public class SummonOrb : Item
{
   public GameObject summonedCreaturePrefab;

   public override void UseItem(Player player)
   {
      Debug.Log(string.Format("You summoned a {0}", this.summonedCreaturePrefab.name));

      Instantiate(this.summonedCreaturePrefab);
   }
}
```

Then change your `UseItem` method in `Player`:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void UseItem()
   {
      if (this.itemInHand != null)
      {
         this.itemInHand.UseItem(this);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion above. It seems like item is returning a null value in the Player script and throws an error for the itemInHand variable. Should I reference this somewhere else beforehand and set a value?

Comment: My other question, and I guess the other important part is this:  

I understand that I cannot add Monobehaviors to scriptable objects. But, If I'm creating items through scriptable objects, how would I give them unique behaviors and call them when the player wants to use them?

I'm assuming I have to write specific scripts for each unique behavior(for each item). But within those, would I just use a UseItem() method to replace the itemObject UseItem() method?

Comment: 1) Did you assign the `item` property in the Inspector of the object that contains the `ItemDisplay` script?  2) You can put methods on `ScriptableObjects` that interact with stuff in your game and scene, just like you would with a `MonoBehaviour`.  The difference is that since it's a `ScriptableObject` instead of a `MonoBehaviour`, it won't have methods like `Start`, `Update`, etc.  You can do unique behaviors either through a bunch of if/thens or by making derived classes from your `Item` scriptable object (I recommend the later).

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to give unique behavior to each item.

Comment: 1) You're right that the item property didn't have a value, but it's not accepting a script nor a prefab. I'm afraid I'm not sure what to try. I know I'm close!

Comment: The `item` property is where you should drag the `ScriptableObject` that you created.  First, create the `ScriptableObject` in your Project view (right click, `Create` -> `Item` or however you named the `CreateAssetMenu`), then drag that `ScriptableObject` instance into your `ItemDisplay.item` property.

Comment: The script for your `ScriptableObject` is different than the `ScriptableObject` instances that you create in your Project view.  The script is like the blueprint.  But then you have to make one or more items based off that blueprint.  That's what creating the scriptable object instance(s) in your Project view does.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! For some reason I thought that my item with fields was already attached. I'll try to implement the unique behaviors next!